# Categorical selection for a list in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, selection

I have a list of numbers and colors in a table:

Example:

```
1.9   green  black  
2.3   red    black
3.3   green  black
8.2   red    black
0.1   green  white
10.2  green  white
```

I am trying to write a selection structure that sorts different types of colors in different lists.

This is what I got:

```
`import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('hw03_problem2.csv' , skiprows=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['num','gb','bw'])

#df=df.astype(float)
f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
print(df)
df[df.gb == 'green'].num.plot.hist(ax = ax1)
df[df.gb == 'red'].num.plot.hist(ax = ax2)
df[df.bw == 'black'].num.plot.hist(ax = ax3)
df[df.bw == 'white'].num.plot.hist(ax = ax4)


plt.show()
plt.savefig('subplot_for_q2')
~
```

~
~
~
~

Comment: Can you explain your expected output more? What exactly do you need to plot against what, given your sample data.

Comment: Thx for reply! It's very simple. I wish to create four subplots of histograms. Each histogram contains the data set for a type of color.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty unclear what you're trying to do. Why don't you try reading the data in with `df = pd.read_csv('hw03_problem2.csv', names=['number', 'color1', 'color2']), which should make it much easier to deal with.

You can then plot a particular subset with

```py
df[df.color1 == 'black'].number.plot.hist(ax=ax1)
```

if you already have the axes set up. That's assuming it's the numbers you're making the histogram of.

Comment: \ I have applied the changes that you suggest, but its giving me an new error that Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot\